# Underscore vertical alignment with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, underscore

I would like to have an underscore aligned with other text inside a tikz array, but it is shown at middle of the box, as shown in this picture and it can be confused with an hyphen:

[image]

This is my code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    %  -{Stealth[length = 2.5pt]},
    start chain = going right,
    node distance = 0pt,
    Array/.style={draw, minimum width=2em, minimum height=2em, 
        outer sep=0pt, on chain},
    ]
    \node [Array] (1) {\texttt{A}};
    \node [Array] (2) {\texttt{\_}};
    \node [Array] (3) {\texttt{B}};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: `Array/.style={execute at begin node=\strut,...}`

Comment: Right, or even just `\node [Array] (2) {\strut \texttt{\_}};` in this case, if you have only one to process. And also, be kind to provide a complete MWE, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` in the future ;)

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to the `\strut` suggested in comments, you could set `text height`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    %  -{Stealth[length = 2.5pt]},
    start chain = going right,
    node distance = 0pt,
    Array/.style={draw, minimum width=2em, text height=1.25ex, minimum height=2em, 
        outer sep=0pt, on chain},
    ]
    \node [Array] (1) {\texttt{A}};
    \node [Array] (2) {\texttt{\_}};
    \node [Array] (3) {\texttt{B}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A (very) small variation of nice @CarLaTeX answer (+1) -- defined is the common (a little bit different) style for all nodes:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 0pt,
  start chain = going right,
        nodes = {draw, minimum width=2em, outer sep=0pt,
                     text height=1.75ex, text depth=0.25ex,
                     font=\ttfamily, on chain},
                        ]
\node   (1) {A};
\node   (2) {\_};
\node   (3) {B};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]